# NSMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row crashes

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, ipad

I have a UITableViewController with an NSMutableArray in the header like this:

```
NSMutableArray *someArray;
```

Also I have the property declared:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *someArray;
```

In the .m file I load the array in the method:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    someArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self loadArrayData];

    [tableview reloadData];
}
```

The table populates great, adding is no problem, but when I try to delete a row, the app crashes on the following line:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    [someArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //update table etc..
```

If I use the debugger, I can see the array has some objects, and when I Log indexPath.row I get a value which is inside the array size.

I don't understand why it is crashing on this line... Who can help me?

The console outputs:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6193890'

Comment: A little more information on what the crash is may help. What kind of crash is occurring?

Comment: Sorry, I've added the console error output..

Comment: Hmmm, I honestly don't know. It's obvious an invalid argument is being passed to removeObjectAtIndex:. However indexPath.row should return an NSUInteger which is a valid argument.

Comment: That's the exact same thing I was thinking... Also passing just value 0 into the method causes it to crash...

Comment: and you are 100% sure that the array doesn't get replaced by an immutable array at some place? Check again.

Comment: I have a very similar issue. What is interesting is that the first 25 objects can each be removed with no problem. Issues occur from 26 onwards.

Comment: I had the same issue. Check that in your loadArrayData, you are not calling some NSArray call to get info. What I had done was called [NSArray arrayWithObjects: ... ]  which returned an immutable instance.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem and I was initiating my array with CoreData like this:

```
self.allContacts = (NSMutableArray*)[cdc.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

trying to cast the result from CoreDataController fetch request to NSMutableArray.

Turns out I need the function called "mutableCopy" at the end of fetch request.

```
self.allContacts = (NSMutableArray*)[[cdc.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];
```

I don't think cast to (MutableArray *) is required but I have it just in case.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue a week back. What I did was this:

Declared a NSMutableArray* globalArray as a global within the same tableViewController.m implementation file. Then inside

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
   globalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:someArray];
   [globalArray removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; 
}
```

And then I copied back this globalArray into someArray before the reloadData call. Works.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply! It fixed the issue I was facing, but now it crashes on the line UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; in tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You should not "fix" your bugs with such hacks.

Answer (score 0):

1. not sure if that cause one of your issues, but if you have property for `someArray` then use `self.someArray` instead of just `someArray` .
   Of course that after using self, you should auto release it like this :

> self.someArray = [[[NSMutableArray
>   alloc] init] autorelease];
>
> (call this inside your viewController
>   init method)

then try to :

```
[self.someArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

2.
 try to call  `[self loadArrayData];` inside `viewDidLoad`.
It should be called prior to cellForRowAtIndexPath, and that way you won't need to call `reloadData`

if that still won't help, then post the code of `loadArrayData`

Comment: Hi, I will try that when I get home. The problem why I call reloadData is because I have a navigationcontroller, which has an "Add" button, it pushes the view to a new view where the user can input some details, and when he hits "Save" the navigationcontroller gets popped back and then it has to reload the data because the user just entered a new record... How can I accomplish that without reloadData?

Comment: You can pass the array you want to update to the new viewController and update it there. And isn't the tableView getting reloaded by itself when you go back to the tableViewController ? don't think you need to call reloadData.